# Visualize Sensor_msgs/PointCloud2

Tags: c++, qt, ros, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am trying to visualize realtime **sensor_msgs/PointCloud2** on my qtvtk widget instead of reading from **.pcd file**. I will share an example of code that reads from .pcd file.

```
void MainWindow::imageShowLIDAR( const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2& msg)
{
    //std::cout << "carico file" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "imageshow lidar initiated" << std::endl;
    
    cloud_pcl.reset (new PointCloudT);
    cloud_pcl->resize (200);
    red   = 128;
    green = 128;
    blue  = 128;
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile("/home/rack_dl/RCEDS_V5/Data/pcl1.pcd", *cloud_pcl);
    //pcl::io::loadPCDFile("/home/rack_dl/RCEDS_V5/Data/Reg.pcd", *cloud_pcl);
    for (auto& point: *cloud_pcl)
  {
    //point.x = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
    //point.y = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
    //point.z = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);

    point.r = red;
    point.g = green;
    point.b = blue;
    
  }
    
    viewer_pcl.reset(new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer("viewer_pcl", false));
    //Set viewer settings

    viewer_pcl->addCoordinateSystem(3.0, "coordinate");
    viewer_pcl->setShowFPS(false);
    viewer_pcl->setBackgroundColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0);
    //viewer_pcl->setCameraPosition(0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0);
    ui.LIDAR_Widget->SetRenderWindow(viewer_pcl->getRenderWindow());
    viewer_pcl->setupInteractor(ui.LIDAR_Widget->GetInteractor(), ui.LIDAR_Widget->GetRenderWindow());
    viewer_pcl->addPointCloud (cloud_pcl, "cloud");
    viewer_pcl->resetCamera ();
    ui.LIDAR_Widget->update();
    
}
```

I am recieving data on sensor_msgs/PointCloud2

Instead of reading from .pcd file i want to visualize realtime. How do i do it?

Comment: is using RVIZ a no go?

Comment: @ignacio yeah i am using my own visualizer similar to pclviewer from pointcloud. All the online help only revolves around reading from the .,pcd file.

Comment: as you already have it working for `.pcd` you should get something to convert the `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` to the same point cloud type as `cloud_pcl`. Probably using [`pcl_ros/conversions.h`](http://docs.ros.org/en/hydro/api/pcl/html/ros_2conversions_8h.html)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Ignacio. You should take a look at the pcl_conversions package!

Here's an example of a callback in ROS2:

```
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
void cloud_callback(const sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::SharedPtr &msg){
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> pcl_cloud;

  pcl::fromROSMsg(*msg,pcl_cloud);

  // pcl_cloud -> point_cloud as pcl object

  // code here
  //    ...
  // code here

  sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2 sensor_msgs_cloud;

  pcl::toROSMsg(pcl_cloud,sensor_msgs_cloud);

  // sensor_msgs_cloud -> point_cloud as sensor_msgs object
}
```

For ROS1 you should have to change the `#include` and the namespaces a bit. But the code is pretty much the same. You can take a look at the [github repo](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/blob/melodic-devel/pcl_conversions/test/test_pcl_conversions.cpp) example to get a hint of how it should look like.

For the real-time visualization update, you should look at the [official pcl tutorial](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/mobile_streaming.html).